# ReportViewer in multiview not refreshing after postback

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, multiview

I have a report that is inside of a multiview. The first view is the criteria and the second is the report. This used to work just fine. I recently upgrade the project to VS2010 without touching the reports and it continued to work. Today I updated the report to be a 2010 rdlc and it's not working anymore.

If I move the report out of the multi-view and just place it somewhere on the page it works just fine. How can i cause the report to load on postback? I am adding a parameter to my object data source in the code behind so I can see that when the report is outside the multiview the select event gets triggered; but it does not get triggered when the report is inside the multiview.

What can I do to cause the report to load on postback when it becomes visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a place that had the answer. Read this blog if you are curious: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/11/16/the-invisible-reportviewer.aspx